# Android get EXIF data from content URI

Tags: android

I'm trying to get exif data of a picture I take. However ExifInterface either takes a file path that I cannot give it since it's a "content" resource, or an InputStream but this works only for API 24+ (which I cannot allow). Do you know of any other options I could retrieve the orientation of my pic with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However ExifInterface either takes a file path that I cannot give it since it's a "content" resource, or an InputStream but this works only for API 24+ (which I cannot allow)

`android.support.media.ExifInterface` supports `InputStream`, works on older devices (since it comes from the Android Support libraries), and is not the security-bug-riddled `android.media.ExifInterface` that nobody should be using.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the support library:

- add compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.1' to your
  build.gradle file
- use class android.support.media.ExifInterface
  instead of android.media.ExifInterface